# Node.js Socket.io error: disconnect event is triggered after connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

- On server the disconnect event is triggered after connect when the network had 
  dropped and the client reconnects.

**Client code:**

```
var url ='192.168.1.101', port = '80',
    socket = io.connect('http://' + url + ':' + port, {
    'reconnect': true,
    reconnection: true,
    reconnectionDelay: 1000,
    reconnectionDelayMax: 5000,
    timeout: 1000
});
```

//reconnect event

```
socket.on('reconnect', function (nr) {
    console.log('reconnected, nr: ', nr);
});
```

//connect event

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('connected');
});
```

//disconnect event

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('disconnected');
});
```

**Server code:**

```
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs'),
    express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    io = require('socket.io'),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    compress = require('compression'),
    socket;

app.use(compress({level: 9}));

server.listen(port, url);
socket = io.listen(server, {'pingTimeout': 1000, 'pingInterval': 3000});

socket.on('connection', function (client) {
    console.log('client connected');

    client.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('client disconnected');
    });
});
```

```
        
- Result on server if client reconnects:

> client connected
> client disconnected

Can someone explain to me why this is happening?
```

Comment: Does it attempt to reconnect? or does it just disconnect and thats it?

Answer (score 0):

The client and server exchange heart beat messages while the connection is active. When the server stops receiving these messages it will declare the client disconnected. The client can also disconnect explicitly.

What you are experiencing though is probably the first case. The client has a retry logic so whenever the connection is dropped it'll try to reconnect. I'm not sure why this is happen, you may want to look at the network tab in your browser's console to see what's happening at the request/response level.

REF: 
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1910

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/116

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the `client disconnected` and `client connected` texts are from the same socket/connection? Maybe first one is from previous connection and it is just delivered to you a bit later than info about new connection?

Try to generate and add some ID numbers to connections/sockets and output them to console along with info messages.

Comment: On reconnect a new client is connected and the old one is disconnected, the id numbers are different...

Comment: So everything is OK. You're getting correct events. It's just that they are delivered to you in different order than one could assume. But that's ok too - you should not depend on order of asynchronous events, from different sources.

Comment: I am working on a chat app so if the disconnect event is triggered the user is deleted from the users list... It's reconnected and disconnected...

Comment: But that's normal isn't it? You cannot know, from the server point of view, if client is reconnecting right now or not. Reconnection means that new connection will be created.

Comment: You can try to mark connections with some user ID, keep list of connected users somewhere and then, on disconnect event, check if user is still connected through some other socket or not. That way, if "connected" happens before "disconnected", you will, for example, have something like `user.connections` equal 2, and after "disconnected" it will become 1. Only after it becomes 0 you will assume that user disconnected and remove it from the list.

Comment: I thought that it will re-establish the connection with same client, but I was wrong. Thank your for your answers!